# Can we use wsdl2Objc with ASIHTTPRequest Library?

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

Is it possible to use ASIHTTPRequest to call web services that are made available through WSDL. I used wsdl2Objc Library to get the Webservice classes.

Is it possible for us to use the ASIHTTPRequest to invoke those services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, wsdl2Objc has methods to invoke services. I am planning to use it. I also came to know that, I can change the implementation of wsdl2objc library to have other Webservice Invocation implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple (and automatic) way to do SOAP request on iPhone.

My solution: I use soapUI to generate a sample request. I transform this request in a string format by replacing parameters with %@. And I add it in the project.

It works, but it's a dirt way, if your wisdl change you have to re-do everything

PS: ASIHTTPRequest is no longer supported, use AFNetworking instead.